# Is it a bug of Mongoid or Rails3 ?  Here are full codes that you can reproduce the strange 'bug'  

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, nested-attributes, autosave

```
$ rails -v
Rails 3.1.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p312 (2011-08-11 revision 32926) [i686-linux]
```

**If you want to reproduce the problem, just follow me:**

**First, create these three model(just copy):**

```
#school.rb
class School
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :students

end
```

---

```
#student.rb
class Student
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  has_many :books
  belongs_to :school

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :books

end
```

---

```
#book.rb
class Book
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name

  belongs_to :student

  validate :check

  def check
    # The calling for the 'school' method caused the issue
    self.student.school
  end

end
```

**Second, run your console and paste:**

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :001 > School.destroy_all;Student.destroy_all; Book.destroy_all; School.create
ruby-1.9.2-head :001 >  Student.create school_id: School.first.id, 'books_attributes' => {'1' => {'name' => 'I am a book'}}
```

---

Then, let's see what happend:

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :002 > Book.count
MONGODB xxx_development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"books", "query"=>{}, "fields"=>nil})
=> 2
```

And even more, if you set  the 'student has_many books' relation to 'autosave: true':

```
class Student
 ......
 has_many :books, autosave: true
 ......
end
```

**Let's see what will happend:**

```
ruby-1.9.2-head :001 > School.destroy_all;Student.destroy_all; Book.destroy_all; School.create
ruby-1.9.2-head :001 >  Student.create school_id: School.first.id, 'books_attributes' => {'1' => {'name' => 'I am a book'}}
ruby-1.9.2-head :002 > Student.count
MONGODB xxx_development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"students", "query"=>{}, "fields"=>nil})
 => 2 

ruby-1.9.2-head :004 > Student.all.to_a
MONGODB xxx_development['students'].find({})
 => [#<Student _id: 4f62a8341d41c81bc6000002, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-03-16 02:40:52 UTC, updated_at: 2012-03-16 02:40:52 UTC, school_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f62a8341d41c81bc6000001')>, #<Student _id: 4f62a8341d41c81bc6000003, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-03-16 02:40:52 UTC, updated_at: 2012-03-16 02:40:52 UTC, school_id: nil>] 

ruby-1.9.2-head :005 > Book.count
MONGODB xxx_development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"books", "query"=>{}, "fields"=>nil})
 => 2
ruby-1.9.2-head :006 > Book.all.to_a
MONGODB xxx_development['books'].find({})
 => [#<Book _id: 4f62a8341d41c81bc6000003, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-03-16 02:40:52 UTC, updated_at: 2012-03-16 02:40:52 UTC, name: "I am a book", student_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f62a8341d41c81bc6000002')>, #<Book _id: 4f62a8341d41c81bc6000002, _type: nil, created_at: 2012-03-16 02:40:52 UTC, updated_at: 2012-03-16 02:40:52 UTC, name: nil, student_id: nil>]
```

This bug really run me crazy.
Why there are **additional models** when calling 'school' in a book validate method?

Or there is something I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is fine here, you're not doing anything incorrect - but Mongoid has no issue with this same code on master or 2.4.x. See my suggestions here to find the culprit:

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1826

Comment: Thank you Durran, when I created a new empty rails app to test it, the issue still existed;
But after updating my mongoid(2.3.x) to the lastest version from github, everything works fine now.

: )